# Fx forward valuation in QuantLib-Python

Tags: python, derivative, quantlib

Is there any possibility to value fx instruments in QuantLib-Python (especially, fx forwards, fx swaps)? For the last two days I have been looking through the documentation but I have only found "one currency" instruments like "VanillaSwap" and etc. Probably, one could use other libraries that are based on QuantLib... Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

FX forward is currently not supported. Not sure about the swap.